# Animated en un while

Tags: html, while, animación

estoy introduciendo animaciones y me encuentro con una cosa que no se como solventarla.

Estoy sacando un ciclo while que me hace un bucle de col-4 para sacar unos testimonios de la BD con un limite de los 3 últimos.

Bien, le pongo la animación en el col-4 para que esa misma se reproduzca en los 3 col-4 pero solo se me reproduce en el primero.

```
<?php
 //var_dump($_GET);
 $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT valoraciones.id, valoraciones.idUser, valoraciones.Estrellas, valoraciones.Valoracion, valoraciones.Publicada, Usuarios.IdUsuario, Usuarios.Nombre, Usuarios.Sexo FROM valoraciones, Usuarios WHERE valoraciones.idUser = Usuarios.IdUsuario AND valoraciones.Publicada = 1 ORDER BY valoraciones.id DESC LIMIT 3 ");
 mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
 while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
?>

<div id="MovTesti" class="col-4">TESTIMONIO</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Podrías ponernos el **Java Script** o lo que estés usando para tratar de darle la animación que nos comentas? De primeras ya estoy viendo que en el blucle estás generando un elemento con la misma **ID** múltiples veces, podrían ir por ahí los tiros pero sin ver nada más del código me resulta imposible afinar más.

Comment: Si no seria ningún problema hacerlo con JavaScript, pero no conozco mucho. Seria más fácil hacer que lea una ID diferente?

Comment: Al hablar de  "animaciones" pensé que estabas tratando de realizarlas con Java Script, ya que es una tarea de las que se le suele destinar a este lenguaje. ¿A qué te refieres exactamente con "animaciones? ¿Cuál es el efecto que deseas conseguir? Cuando dices que "le pongo la animación en el col-4", ¿qué animación le estás poniendo? Realmente no se comprende bien lo que pretendes conseguir.

Comment: perdona no explique bien esa parte, se trata de animations.css, en este caso estamos poniendo `jackInTheBox`

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de animación? ¿Aparecer y desaparecer? ¿Moverse a un lado o a otro? ¿Desplegarse y plegarse? Hay muchos tipos de animaciones. Cuanto mejor expliques lo que pretendes conseguir, mejor ayuda podremos ofrecerte.

Comment: es más bien una sacudida, https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ jackInTheBox

Comment: Aquí tienes un enlace a una sección de código que podría ayudarte. Tan solo tendrías que copiar el CSS que ahí tienes y darle las mismas clases a tu elemento HTML. https://codepen.io/rpem/pen/JRPaEq

Comment: Pero al tener cargado ya animated.css ya tengo esas animaciones, ese no es el problema, cre...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que estoy leyendo, la librería que tienes instalada lo único que te pide es que le des dos clases al elemento que deseas animar. No he podido desplegar un escenario de pruebas, pero presuntamente tu código funcionaría así.

```
<?php
 //var_dump($_GET);
 $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT valoraciones.id, valoraciones.idUser, valoraciones.Estrellas, valoraciones.Valoracion, valoraciones.Publicada, Usuarios.IdUsuario, Usuarios.Nombre, Usuarios.Sexo FROM valoraciones, Usuarios WHERE valoraciones.idUser = Usuarios.IdUsuario AND valoraciones.Publicada = 1 ORDER BY valoraciones.id DESC LIMIT 3 ");
 mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
 while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
?>

<div id="MovTesti" class="col-4" class="jackInTheBox animated"><p>TESTIMONIO</p></div>

<?php } ?>
```

Lo único que he hecho ha sido añadirle las clases **jackInTheBox animated** al **HTML** que has puesto en el ejemplo, además de meter el texto dentro de un `<p>`.

**EDIT**

Al no tener más de tu código desconozco si has realizado una instalación correcta de la librería, pero suponiendo que sí que sea el caso, debería funcionarte.

**EDIT 2**

Podrías usar una variable autoincremental para concatenársela a la **ID** y de esta manera generarla dinámica y únicamente:

```
<?php
 //var_dump($_GET);
 $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT valoraciones.id, valoraciones.idUser, valoraciones.Estrellas, valoraciones.Valoracion, valoraciones.Publicada, Usuarios.IdUsuario, Usuarios.Nombre, Usuarios.Sexo FROM valoraciones, Usuarios WHERE valoraciones.idUser = Usuarios.IdUsuario AND valoraciones.Publicada = 1 ORDER BY valoraciones.id DESC LIMIT 3 ");
 mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
 $contador = 1;
 while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
?>

<div id="MovTesti_<?php echo $contador; $contador++; ?>" class="col-4" class="jackInTheBox animated"><p>TESTIMONIO</p></div>

<?php } ?>
```

**EDIT 3**

Para que la animación tenga un delay de 3 segundos.

```
$('clase_que_tienes_que_poner_a_los_elementos_que_necesitas_animar').waypoint(function(){ $('this').addClass('jackInTheBox animated delay-3s'); }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero de este modo se activa al actualizar la web no al pasar por el div como lo tengo en los otros sitios

Comment: En los otros añado esto:   $('#EquipoS').css('opacity', 0);
        $('#EquipoS').waypoint(function(){
          $('#EquipoS').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
        },{
          offset: '90%'
        });  Para que cuando llegue al div se ponga en marcha

Comment: El código ya lo tienes entonces. Lo que tendrías que hacer es darle las clases que te interesan al elemento que necesitas. Modificando lo que acabas de poner quedaría algo así: $('clase_que_tienes_que_poner_a_los_elementos_que_necesitas_animar').waypoint(function(){ $('this').addClass('jackInTheBox animated'); }

Comment: Para que esto funcione, debes añadir al **div** del HTML de tu bucle, una clase para que sirva de identificador. Sustituyendo a la que te pongo yo de ejemplo: **"clase_que_tienes_que_poner_a_los_elementos_que_necesitas_animar"**.

Comment: Listo! lo hice igual pero por ID no por class. No sabia que existia esa diferencia

Comment: Cuidado, no es bueno que tengas la misma ID en varios elementos HTML, yo solucionaría eso y le pondría la clase que te comento. Si te ha servido no olvides poner la respuesta como correcta ^^

Comment: como soluciono el dar distinto id, nunca lo hice en un while

Comment: He editado mi respuesta de arriba para responderte a esa última pregunta. Está en **EDIT 2**

Comment: Listo ahora si! sabes como puedo ponerle un delay??

Comment: Según la documentación de la librería **animations.css** tan solo tendrías que añadirle una clase más para darle un delay de los segundos que necesites. Vuelvo a editar mi respuesta en **EDIT 3**.